# HTTP_REFERER coming back with NULL, key does not exist in $_SERVER

Tags: php, http-referer

For the first time since using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it gives me `NULL` as a result.

When I do `var_dump($_SERVER)` the `HTTP_REFERER` key does not exist.

I also try to visit site with different browsers and from different sites but with no result.

The website is running on a Linux/Apache based server.

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to track from where visitor come to my site php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734825/how-to-track-from-where-visitor-come-to-my-site-php)

Comment: HOW are you visiting your site FROM other sites? by klicking on a link that points to your own site? or are you just going on for example google and then typing in the url to your page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all browsers will send the HTTP Referer header - you can't rely on it being sent.  For instance, there are plenty of privacy addons which will disable sending of the header, or always send something specific rather than the real referring URL.

A proxy between you and the server could also choose not to pass on this header.

Also, of course, if you've gone straight to the URL in question, there is no referring URL to report.

Answer (score 4):

The [**`Referer`** HTTP header](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTTP_referrer) is **optional** : clients can choose not to send it *(or to send a false value)*.

This means you application can use it -- but **must not depend on it**.